# LLDB not showing variables values when inside a C++ class virtual method

Tags: c++, c++11, xcode9, lldb

I am currently using an open source library for Finance and building my own extension on top of it. Library dependency is built under Xcode 9.2  in Debug mode, and is included as a framework dependency to my executable. When I run lldb on my target, the debugger shows values and the stack trace for the linked library objects/methods, but as soon as a (virtual) method of the implementation of an interface/abstract class is called, LLDB ceases to show the values inside this method. It keeps showing the Debug values for normal std:: containers though.

Can someone please help me understand? Is this an issue in the current implementation of LLDB?

Comment: Honestly sounds like a bug.  You might be able to work around this temporarily with some printf() calls if needed.  I'll let others confirm this though.

Comment: Can you give a more complete description of what you see?  Does Xcode correctly show the source file for this virtual method?  Are there NO variables listed in the variables view for this method or are only some missing?  Are they listed but have no values?  Maybe a screen shot showing the problem would help.

Answer (score 0):

I am attaching two screenshots with the debugger: one for the function call right before the "non-virtual thunk to ..." and one just after. Moving the cursor above the variable shows the values of the data members in the non virtual call, but not in the virtual one. 
[Before call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOKaK.jpg)

[After call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NRlj.jpg)

Comment: From the pictures you added, I can tell that lldb did find debug information for both stop locations.  That's good...  But they don't show what locals we've found in the failure case.  Can you also show me what the variables view shows in the failure case?  You can open that by clicking on the left one of the two widgets on the far right of the filter bar below the Debugger Console window.  At the point where you are stopped, it looks like the only variable is `this` so the interesting bit of information would be the contents of `this`.